# Trying to mimic the fsolve function from Python in a cpp scritp for simple functions

Tags: python, c++, math, symbolic-math, algebra

First of all, I'm new to C++. Tbh I find it very hard to "get used to" but the last week I have been trying to "translate" a script from Python to C++ due to computational time requirements.

One of the problem I have is **root-finding of simple 1D functions**:

First the simple  MWE from Python:
Trying to solve  *ax^2+bx+c = 0* :

```
def f(x,a,b,c):
   return a*x**2+b*x+c
optimize.fsolve(f,-1.0e2,args=(1,1,-1))
```

which will return either `-1.618` or `0.618` depending on the starting's guess sign

Ok, in C++ from what I have searched online is a bit more complicated and used the [GSL Root finding](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/roots.html#c.gsl_root_fsolver_bisection) library.

For simple non-polyonimal functions, it works like a charm, but when second order come in,
**the addition of endpoints** seem to be a problem when you simpled search for a "quick" solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <functional>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_interp2d.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline2d.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_roots.h>


struct my_f_params { double a; double b; double c; };

double
my_f (double x, void * p)
  {
    struct my_f_params * params = (struct my_f_params *)p;
    double a = (params->a);
    double b = (params->b);
    double c = (params->c);

    return  (a * x + b) * x + c;
  }

double root (struct my_f_params prms, double r)
{
  int status;
  int iter = 0, max_iter = 50;
  const gsl_root_fsolver_type *T;
  gsl_root_fsolver *s;
  double x_lo= -5e0, x_hi=11e0;
  gsl_function F;
   

  F.function = &my_f;
  F.params = &prms;

  T = gsl_root_fsolver_falsepos;
  s = gsl_root_fsolver_alloc (T);
  gsl_root_fsolver_set (s, &F, x_lo, x_hi);




  do
    {
      iter++;
      gsl_set_error_handler_off();
      status = gsl_root_fsolver_iterate (s);
      r = gsl_root_fsolver_root (s);
      x_lo = gsl_root_fsolver_x_lower (s);
      x_hi = gsl_root_fsolver_x_upper (s);
      status = gsl_root_test_interval (x_lo, x_hi,
                                       0, 0.001);
    printf("%f  %f\n",x_lo,x_hi);
    }
  while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < max_iter);


  return r;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   struct my_f_params params = {1, 1, -1};
   printf("root of x2+x1-1=0 %f\n",  root(params,1.25));
  return 0;
}
```

now, if the starting `x_lo , x_hi` cover the 2 solution integrals, it does not proceed to finding *the closest* one, giving the error

```
gsl: falsepos.c:74: ERROR: endpoints do not straddle y=0
Default GSL error handler invoked.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Have tried a lot of things from google before I posted here.

Really really thank you for your time, anything is appreciated!

Comment: `endpoints do not straddle y=0` suggests that the problem is that the root-finder expects f(a) < 0 and f(b) > 0 or vice versa where a and b are the endpoints and f is the function of interest. In order to find such an interval, you'll have to apply some heuristic to find a and b, then you can call the root finder. E.g. evaluate f for k, k + 1, k + 2, k + 3, ... until you find f(k) < 0 and f(k + 1) > 0 or vice versa. There are many other possible heuristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to look into this similar issue with good explanation how to make it work [error in GSL - root finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079912/error-in-gsl-root-finding).
To help, you can use https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zuaqvcvpbz to view the function, and you can set initial values like this:
double x_lo = 0.0, x_hi = 1.0;
in your implementation to make it run;
Adding this code will help to find appropriate values for x_lo and x_hi :

```
gsl_set_error_handler_off(); // this turns off error reporting
int check = gsl_root_fsolver_set(s, &F, x_lo, x_hi);
if (check == GSL_EINVAL) {// this is the error code you got
    do {
        x_lo += 0.1;  // it would be appropriate to check the sign in both 
        x_hi -= 0.1;  // cases, to make sure interval is adjusted properly
        check = gsl_root_fsolver_set(s, &F, x_lo, x_hi);
    } while (check != 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Valeca.

What you are saying is essentially the problem on a tick deeper. What I want to achieve is something similar to FSOLVE from Python. That's because, i want to regulary pass functions and solve them. But I can't systematically check to find end points with different sign. 

Is there a way around it?

Comment: I updated my answer to address this ( its just general idea, which needs to be enhanced for some cases, like different signs or smaller step than 0.1.

Comment: I see alright, I will try to implement it above. Is it ok to reply to you tommorow? (too late here)

Comment: I implemented the part of the code on that example. It worked correctly. Would there be a more generic way to solve this problem, you think?

Comment: This is how it is recommended in manual from GSL. Not sure what you mean by 'generic' way. It depends on requirements, I would say.